# If block always goes to else in Bash

Tags: bash

The following segment of code goes to the `else` statement when it should be going into the `elif`.

```
#The following line returns 3, 4 or 5 as the exit code.
$BASH_EXEC adbE.sh "adb $ARGUMENT install $f"
echo "the return code:$?."
if [ $? -eq 5 ]
then
    #do nothing, success
    continue
elif [ $? -eq 4 ]
then
    echo "WARNING"
else
    echo "ERROR"
    break
fi
```

This part: `echo "the return code:$?."` echoes this to the screen: `the return code:4.`

And it does not display `WARNING`. It only displays `ERROR` and then breaks the `for` loop this code is contained in.

What am i doing wrong?

---

Here are the variations of the condition compare that i have tried resulting in the same issue:

1. `if [ $? -eq 5 ]`
2. `if [ $? -eq "5" ]`
3. `if [ $? == 5 ]`
4. `if [ $? == "5" ]`
5. `if [[ $? -eq 5 ]]`
6. `if [[ $? -eq "5" ]]`
7. `if [[ $? == "5" ]]`
8. `if [[ $? == 5 ]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that `$?` is the return code for the **last executed command**. You are running an `echo` command before the `if`, so it is the return code of `echo` that you are testing, which is always going to be 0.

Also, in your case, there is an additional problem caused by the fact that you are retesting the return value in the `elif` statement. The initial test (i.e. `[ $? -eq 5 ]`) will also change the value of `$?`, so retesting it will give an unexpected result.

To fix this situation, save the previous return code before doing the `echo`, and then use the saved version for all future tests:

```
ret=$?
echo "the return code:${ret}."
if [ ${ret} -eq 5 ]
then
        #do nothing, success
        continue
elif [ ${ret} -eq 4 ]
then
        echo "WARNING"
else
        echo "ERROR"
        break
fi
```

Comment: I took the `echo "the return code:$?."` out and the only command before the if block is the command i want the return from. And it still failed. HOWEVER, i used the variable assigning method you mentioned and it worked. Why did removing `echo "the return code:$?."` not fix the issue? Just removing `echo "the return code:$?."` should have worked since the returned value would be `4`. Thanks

Comment: You're right, removing the echo should have fixed it. But as you have not posted any code from before this point I cannot tell why it did not :-/

Comment: Just added the line above the `echo`. It just returns 3, 4 or 5 as the exit code.

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the slightly complicated way you are invoking the previous command. What is in `$BASH_EXEC`?

Comment: Should that even matter, since i know for a fact that i am getting `4` back as the exit code? All i did was take out the `echo` statement, which was showing us that `4` was the return code.

Comment: You are completely correct. It shouldn't matter, that's why I'm looking for other things that may be the cause the issue. Can you try replacing the `$BASH_EXEC...` line with `(exit 4)` and see if you still have the issue?

Comment: Well, the line that says `ERROR` i actually have much more verbose logging. I just put `ERROR` there just to show what i felt was needed to solve the issue. Didn't want the post too fluffy.

Comment: Ah! I think I may have cracked it... The test itself is creating a new return value. When you invoke the `test` command (i.e. the `[ $? -eq 5 ]`) its main function is to provide a return value. Hence you cannot then test `$?` again in the `elif` statement.

Comment: Ok, i put `(exit 4)` instead of `$BASH_EXEC adbE.sh "adb $ARGUMENT install $f"` and the `echo "the return code:$?."` is not there. It is still going to the `else` block when it should be going to the `4` block.

Comment: Yep, see my previous comment. I think we've overlapped.

Comment: AH! That makes since! Thanks for the continued help. Wish i could give more +1. =D

Comment: Can you please post that part of the answer in your original answer? This way people can see what the real reason is, without having to read comments. THANKS!

Comment: Yep. I've changed my original answer to include what we've found here.